# XPages Java Error: Error getting property 'dbName' from bean

Tags: java, xpages

Using the [NotesIn9 example from episode 133](http://notesin9.com/index.php/2014/01/13/notesin9-133-using-java-in-xpages-part-2) I tried to adapt the code to a database maintanance XPage. I replaced all the contact stuff with database information: a database form, a database view, a DatabaseModel.java class, a database_crud XPage. And I defined the DatabaseModel.java class as managed bean.
But when I try to open y XPage I get the following error:

Error getting property 'dbName' from bean of type com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule$XPagesDatabase

Here is the managed bean definition:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>database</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-bean-class>org.openntf.howyabean.model.DatabaseModel</managed-bean-class>
</managed-bean>
```

And here the dbName field in the XPage:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <xp:label for="dbName" value="Database Name" />
                            <xp:inputText id="dbName" value="#{database.dbName}" />
                        </div>
```

I'm new to XPages development and don't know where to search for the problem. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the bean name from `database` to something else as `database` is a reserved name.

Comment: This changes the error to: Error testing property 'dbName' in bean of type null

Comment: Did you change faces-config.xml and re-build? do you have a getter and setter for dbName (getDbName() and setDbName())?

Comment: In this example from Tim Tripcony the items are loaded dynamically in a AbstractDocumentMapModel class. So there are no explicit getters and setters.

Comment: Ah, yes. So the bean is null. Check again for spelling mistakes and for build errors.

Comment: I now changed the field names from dbName to database_name, from server to database_server ... And now it works. Perhpas there was another problem with reserved names.